# Using Spacy to Collect Left and Right Entities into a Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spacy

Using Spacy entities, I am attempting to create a Pandas data frame consisting of three columns: entity text, entity text to the left of that entity, and  entity text to the right of that entity.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
with open("./temp_txt.txt", "r") as text_file:
    document_ents = nlp(text_file.read()).ents
df = pd.DataFrame({"left": (document_ents[document_ents.index(ent) - 1].text for ent in document_ents), "raw_text": (ent.text for ent in document_ents), "right": (document_ents[document_ents.index(ent) + 1].text for ent in document_ents)})
```

Returns `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. I understand that this is likely due to the `right` column attempting to access the right entity for the final entity in the document (the index is out of range).

My question is, what is the correct way to approach this problem and achieve the left and right columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this can be resolved using if-else as part of the list comprehension:

```
df["left"] = ["" if (document_ents.index(ent) == 0) else (document_ents[document_ents.index(ent) - 1].text) for ent in document_ents]
df["right"] = ["" if (document_ents.index(ent) > len(document_ents) - 2) else (document_ents[document_ents.index(ent) + 1].text) for ent in document_ents]
```